# how to stop wordpress from stripping or changing my html code, so I can add an embedded iframe in a text block?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, textbox, embed

I am trying to embed an application form on a website and the HTML with iFrame works in the **visual tab** in a **text box** but after I save it - the code changes to be a "link" to the form instead of having the actual form show on the page via an iFrame.

I understand that WP is stripping out or changing the HTML code that it thinks is incorrect or unnecessary but using the "text box" component, the HTML code works great in the "visual tab" but then right after I save the page updates the "text tab" code changes to be a link to the form.

**Is there a HTML code that I can add that will tell Wordpress to stop trying to fix the code?**

I need to find a fix that doesn't need a plugin, doesn't need an admin sidebar with access to "settings" or to have something added to the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will post a reply here because I do not have enough points to add a comment. Can you try to add the iframe in html block and test again? The text block is indeed stripping html tags, that is it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to a plugin or the admin sidebar your options are fairly limited. A few potential solutions would be...

1. Try adding & saving it in the "**text tab**" instead of the **"visual tab"**
   [image: Wordpress Text Tab Image]
2. Use an **"Custom HTML Block"** block instead of a text box. This will work in the way you're wanting the text boxes to work.
3. If you're using Visual Composer or a similar tool you can find a "**Raw Code**" option similar to the Custom HTML Block.

[image: Wordpress Visual Composer Screenshot for RAW Code]